# Get filtered json values

Tags: java, json

I have the following json. I want to get only the titles that have `category:Accident`.i kept a comboBox frm where user can filter the result.If one chooses accident, just titles of accident category are displayed. How can I get that?

json:

```
     [{"category":"Accident","title":"Accident 1"},
      {"category":"Accident","title":"Accident 2"},
        {"category":"Lost","title":"Lost 1"},
        {"category":"Lost","title":"Lost 2"}]
```

Code:

```
JSONParser p = new JSONParser();
results = p.parse(new InputStreamReader(input));
response = (Vector<Map<String, Object>>) results.get("root");
for (int i = 0; i < response.size(); i++) {
    Hashtable hm = (Hashtable) response.get(i);
    HashMap<String, Object> anItem = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    category = hm.get("category").toString();
    String title = hm.get("title").toString();

    anItem.put("category", category);
    anItem.put("title", title);

    listRender.add(anItem); //listRender is an arraylist
}}};

connectionRequest.setPost(false);
connectionRequest.setUrl("http://bbb.com");
connectionRequest.setDuplicateSupported(true);
NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(connectionRequest);
```

Comment: I'd like to help, but it isn't very clear what you're asking here.  Can you be more specific about what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I don't quiet understand "How can I get the key value pair of a certain parameter?". Are you just getting one pair of whatever meets the conditions or you are getting a group of objects that meets the condition? Please add the expectation result.

Comment: i want to show all the titles from the json that have category:accident, not the titles that have category:lost in above json file.. can i do that??

Comment: `jsonObject.getString("category").equals("Accident")`?

Comment: @cricket_007 i've used JSONParser.. there is no getString method. can u explain a bit more??

Comment: I don't know what that JSONParser class is. The point is, though, is just a simple string comparison to filter out certain results.